# Unfortunatley My First App has stopped in emulator

Tags: java, android

I'm trying the first tutorial on Android's official website. This is to showcase a message when clicking on send, but when I click send I get an error.

I have tried certain questions like these but I cannot find an answer for my issue

I'm inexperienced in Java and Android.

The error log:

```
12-18 18:56:33.421: W/Trace(1004): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-18 18:56:33.421: W/Trace(1004): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-18 18:56:33.450: W/Trace(1004): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-18 18:56:33.480: D/AndroidRuntime(1004): Shutting down VM
12-18 18:56:33.490: W/dalvikvm(1004): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     ... 11 more
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:37)
12-18 18:56:33.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):     ... 14 more
12-18 18:56:37.129: I/Process(1004): Sending signal. PID: 1004 SIG: 9
```

Comment: "Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

This looks like your problem. Can we see your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: here is my manifest I chnaged it to DisplayMessage Activity now I do not get any input field or send button when my ap opens

Comment: `<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
           android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>`

Answer (score 5):

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

so make sure you have declared `DisplayMessageActivity` in `AndroidManifest` as :

```
<activity 
   android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: I changed it to DisplayMessage Activity now I do not get any input field or send button when my app opens

Comment: make sure you are setting layout for DisplayMessage Activity?